# PDF to txt python3

Tags: pdf, txt, pypdf

I'm trying to convert pdf file to txt.
`

```
import re
import PyPDF2
with open('123.pdf', 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
    pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    x = pdfreader.numPages
    pageObj = pdfreader.getPage(x + 1)
    text = pageObj.extractText()
    file1 = open(f"C:\\Users\\honorr\\Desktop\\ssssssss\{re.sub('pdf$','txt',pdfFileObj)}", "a")
    file1.writelines(text)
    file1.close()
```

`Errors:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\honorr\Desktop\ssssssss\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    pageobj = pdfreader.getPage(x + 1)
  File "C:\Users\honorr\Desktop\ssssssss\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 477, in getPage
    return self._get_page(pageNumber)
  File "C:\Users\honorr\Desktop\ssssssss\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py", line 492, in _get_page
    return self.flattened_pages[page_number]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`
How to fix it?

So i don't know why i have this errors. Maybe somebody tell me another way to convert from PDF to TXT?

Answer (score 0):

to convert to text, you can use the (pdftotext) package

```
pip install pdftotext
```

To open, and save pdf to text, you can try this out:

```
import pdftotext

# Load your PDF
with open("./123.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

## If it's password-protected
with open("./123.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f, "yourpassword")

## Appending all to one variable for reading
all_pages=[]
for i in range(len(pdf)):
    all_pages += pdf[i]

## Saving as text:
text_file = open("./123.txt", "w") ## this is a path to where you want to save your file 
text_file.write(all_pages)
text_file.close()
```

I really liked the "pdf2docx" this will enable to convert to docx instead of txt. Check the documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/pdf2docx/

My code was something like this:

```
## To install 
pip install pdf2docx

## to convert and save:
from pdf2docx import Converter

pdf_file = './123.pdf'
docx_file = './123.docx'

# convert pdf to docx
cv = Converter(pdf_file)
cv.convert(docx_file)      # all pages by default
cv.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You're setting `x` to the number of pages, but then trying to get page `x + 1`, which doesn't exist. Depending on how the library is implemented (I'm not familiar with PyPDF2), you may need to try `pdfreader.getPage(x)` or `pdfreader.getPage(x - 1)` to get it to work. This will only get the last page in the document though.